# Set value of a column based on other column with an condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I encountered a problem and it can probably be done by iterating over the rows of this DataFrame but there might be a more elegant solution.

I try to create the column 'desired' as a string if the value of col1 is higher than 20. I tried np.where without success.

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hn44w.png)

Who can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for new column by condition:

```
df['desired'] = np.where(df['col1'] > 20, 'col1 is ' + df['col1'].astype(str), '')
```

Comment: Works for me! Before asking I tried str(df['col1']) but something went wrong then.

Comment: `str(val)` working for scalar, in pandas is necessary `df['col1'].astype(str)`

Comment: done. Apparently, only one check mark is allowed per question

Comment: @Rutger - Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
df['desired'] = ''
df.loc[df['col1'] > 20, 'desired'] = 'col1 is ' + df['col1'].astype(str)
```

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [25, 10, 15, 21]})

df['desired'] = ''
df.loc[df['col1'] > 20, 'desired'] = 'col1 is ' + df['col1'].astype(str)

#    col1     desired
# 0    25  col1 is 25
# 1    10            
# 2    15            
# 3    21  col1 is 21
```

**The problem with this**

The power of pandas is in holding structured data. As soon as you combine strings with numeric data, you lose that structure. Manipulating strings is tedious, for example you can't add 1 to the "desired" column.

**A better idea**

It is better to use a Boolean column to signify a desired condition. For example:

```
df['desired'] = df['col1'] > 20
```

This will give a Boolean [True or False] series depending on the condition specified.

Comment: Thanks! With the first solution, I got a ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. The second I have used often but I'm about to export the alerts with the values to some table and prefer to present it next to each other. Thanks again!

Comment: Looking at your explanation of what you are trying to do, you are better off, if at all possible, performing the text enrichment in "some table" - since you are moving across a bunch of expensive strings with duplicate data ("col1 is..").